# synchronize read of variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I can't figure out how to do this. I have this constraint:

- at most 5 threads concurrently can read a variable , **the others must keep in wait** until the variable can be read again.

```java
public void methodA() {
    lockI.lock();
    try {
        while (countIreaders == 5 || modify) {
            conditionI.await();
        }
        countIreaders++;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (condition) {
            countIreaders = 0;
            lockI.unlock();
            conditionI.notifyAll();
        } else {
            lockI.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I made it serial, but it isn't what I want to achieve. How can I modify the code?

Comment: Why do you set `countIreaders` to 0 in your finally block ?

Comment: Could you clarify why it matters how many readers are reading?

Comment: This smells like "how to use the synchronized keyword in java".

Comment: this is a constraint that i have, and it matters.

Comment: @L.Butz i don't have to syncronize anything. i 10000 thread accessing at this method only 5 can be read, with syncronize it is the same as i wrote.

Comment: @yunandtidus when it is possible to read again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not really understand your code but it seems that what your a looking for is a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). A semaphore is useful for thread synchronization. You can create a new semaphore with 5 tokens/permits. like this :

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(5); //initialization in your data structure

//...

public void yourThreadFunction() {
    // [...] in your readers threads:
    // each thread will of course have to use the same semaphore
    // A thread must aquire a token from the semaphore before accessing your variable
    sem.aquire(); //this call hangs until a permit is available
    // read your value and do some computation
    // only 5 threads can be inside this part because of the aquire
    sem.release(); // release the token/permits
}
```